# Standalone build of DPDK on Windows fails for examples application

Tags: windows, compilation, dpdk

Building the example application *skeleton or l2fwd or l3fwd* via DPDK meson with option `-Dexamples=`, creates the binary executable without any warnings or error. But executing the same example as standalone build leads to DPDK build error

```
C:\dpdk\dpdk-21.02\examples\skeleton>gcc basicfwd.c -include rte_config.h -march=native -IC:/include  -Wl,--as-needed -LC:/lib -lrte_cfgfile -lrte_hash -lrte_cmdline -lrte_pci -lrte_ethdev -lrte_meter -lrte_net -lrte_mbuf -lrte_mempool -lrte_rcu -lrte_ring -lrte_eal -lrte_telemetry -lrte_kvargs
In file included from C:/include/rte_eal.h:21,
                 from basicfwd.c:7:
C:/include/rte_bus.h:22:10: fatal error: sys/queue.h: No such file or directory
 #include <sys/queue.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Expectation:

```
C:\dpdk\dpdk-21.02\examples\skeleton>dir
 Directory of C:\dpdk\dpdk-21.02\examples\skeleton

    <DIR>          .
    <DIR>          ..
           163,348 a.exe
             5,458 basicfwd.c
             1,511 Makefile

               322 meson.build
```

Steps to reproduce the error

- Platform: x86_64, Intel E5 2680 Xeon
- OS: windows server 2019
- DPDK version: 21.02
- Meson version: 0.57.1
- Ninja version: 1.10.2
- Pkg-config version: 0.26
- Steps followed: http://doc.dpdk.org/guides/windows_gsg/index.html
- compiler flags: execute `pkg-config --cflags --libs libdpdk`

Comment: @stackinside thanks for the suggestion, have figured out the include is missing. By adding the missing we are able to create the binary, As explained in the question, "why standalone binary compilation with `pkg-config --cflags --libs libdpdk` does not generate the correct flags as `meson -Dexamples=[application] build`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference in the CFLAGS and LDFLAGS when one uses meson `meson -Dexamples=l2fwd build` and `meson build`. In the former scenario, the dependency is pulled from DPDK root folder directly and direct link to `lib/librte_eal/windows/include`. But when DPDK pkg has installed the files under `lib/librte_eal/windows/include` are not copied over which causes build failure.

Checking `meson.build` in `lib/librte_eal/windows/` reveals the only install is for 'rte_os.h', 'rte_virt2phys.h', and 'rte_windows.h'. Folder 'netinet' and 'sys' are skipped. Based on the update from DPDK maintainer, since DPDK on windows is experimental only validation done is with `meson -Dexamples=l2fwd build`. Hence as temporary work around is to use `-I[DPDK folder]\lib\librte_eal\windows\include\`

Note:

1. Thanks to @stackinside for the comment
2. working on DPDK patch to plug the missing files.